# Assigning values to an array of atomic user defined structures

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, compiler-errors, atomic

I'm trying to create an atomic array of a structure variable. But I cannot assign values to any array element.

```
   struct snap {
        int number;
        int timestamp;
    };

atomic<snap> *a_table;

void writer(int i, int n, int t1)
{
    int v, pid;
    int t1;
    a_table = new atomic<snap>[n];
    pid = i;
    while (true)
    {
        v = rand() % 1000;
        a_table[pid % n]->number = v;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(100 * t1));
    }
}
```

The line `a_table[pid % n]->number = v` is showing an error (expression must have pointer type)

Comment: a_table[pid % n].number = v;
This gives an error std::atomic<snap> has no member number

Comment: Ok thanks I'll tinker with it and report what worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a_table[pid % n]` gives you a `std::atomic<snap>`, not a pointer of that type.

However, you cannot do what you want direcly, you need to use [`atomic::store()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/atomic/atomic/store/). So change this:

```
a_table[pid % n]->number = v;
```

to this:

```
snap tmp {v, myTimestamp};
a_table[pid % n].store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

---

PS: Further read: How [std::atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069103/misunderstanding-of-atomic-structs-and-pointers) works.